# Using MailChimp API v3.0 can I filter out results using merge_fields?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I want to use MailChimp's API (v3.0) to get a list of my subscribers. Specifically, I want to only get subscribers with a first name of "Ken". This is the URL I've constructed to do that, but I'm not getting what I want. It returns a list of emails but they do not match my criteria.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible with 3.0?

```
https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members?members.merge_fields.FNAME=Ken
```

Here is the result I'd LIKE to get.

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "email_address": "kenjones@email.com",
      "unique_email_id": "7cd36cf93c",
      "status": "unsubscribed",
      "merge_fields": {
        "FNAME": "Ken",
        "LNAME": "Jones"
      }
]
}
```

Comment: I tried everything I could think of to do that (including having a look at how mailchimp does it on its own UI) but unfortunately I didn't succeed... So now I manage all my user with my own DB and make batch update when needed. An other work-around : segments.